# Android: disable button when TextView match value

Tags: android

I am learning android and here struggling to `disable` the button id `btnWicketIndia` when `TextView` id `wicketsIndiaText` has `" \ 10 "` value.

Also please tell me the way I write code is correct or can optimize.

## MainActivity.java

```
package me.jatinsoni.cricketscorecard;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    int scoreIndia   = 0;
    int wicketsIndia = 0;
    int scoreSA      = 0;
    int wicketsSA    = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // India Buttons
        Button btnSixerIndia  = findViewById(R.id.sixerIndia);
        Button btnFourIndia   = findViewById(R.id.fourIndia);
        Button btnSingleIndia = findViewById(R.id.singleIndia);
        Button btnTwoIndia    = findViewById(R.id.twoIndia);
        Button btnNoIndia     = findViewById(R.id.noIndia);
        Button btnWideIndia   = findViewById(R.id.wideIndia);
        Button btnWicketIndia = findViewById(R.id.wicketIndia);
        // South Africa Buttons
        Button btnSixerSA  = findViewById(R.id.sixerSA);
        Button btnFourSA   = findViewById(R.id.fourSA);
        Button btnSingleSA = findViewById(R.id.singleSA);
        Button btnTwoSA    = findViewById(R.id.twoSA);
        Button btnNoSA     = findViewById(R.id.noSA);
        Button btnWideSA   = findViewById(R.id.wideSA);
        Button btnWicketSA = findViewById(R.id.wicketSA);
        // Reset button
        Button btnResetScore = findViewById(R.id.resetScore);

        btnSixerIndia.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnFourIndia.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSingleIndia.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnTwoIndia.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnNoIndia.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnWideIndia.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnWicketIndia.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSixerSA.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnFourSA.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSingleSA.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnTwoSA.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnNoSA.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnWideSA.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnWicketSA.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnResetScore.setOnClickListener(this);

        displayScoreIndia(scoreIndia, wicketsIndia);
        displayScoreSA(scoreSA, wicketsSA);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Get Buttons IDs
        switch (v.getId()) {

            // India Buttons
            case R.id.sixerIndia: {
                scoreIndia += 6;
                displayScoreIndia(scoreIndia, wicketsIndia);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.fourIndia: {
                scoreIndia += 4;
                displayScoreIndia(scoreIndia, wicketsIndia);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.singleIndia: {
                scoreIndia += 1;
                displayScoreIndia(scoreIndia, wicketsIndia);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.twoIndia: {
                scoreIndia += 2;
                displayScoreIndia(scoreIndia, wicketsIndia);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.noIndia: {
                scoreIndia += 1;
                displayScoreIndia(scoreIndia, wicketsIndia);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.wideIndia: {
                scoreIndia += 1;
                displayScoreIndia(scoreIndia, wicketsIndia);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.wicketIndia: {

                if (String.valueOf(wicketsIndia).equals(" / 10")) {
                    btnWicketIndia.setEnabled(false);
                }

                wicketsIndia += 1;
                displayScoreIndia(scoreIndia, wicketsIndia);
                break;
            }

            // South Africa Buttons
            case R.id.sixerSA: {
                scoreSA += 6;
                displayScoreSA(scoreSA, wicketsSA);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.fourSA: {
                scoreSA += 4;
                displayScoreSA(scoreSA, wicketsSA);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.singleSA: {
                scoreSA += 1;
                displayScoreSA(scoreSA, wicketsSA);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.twoSA: {
                scoreSA += 2;
                displayScoreSA(scoreSA, wicketsSA);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.noSA: {
                scoreSA += 1;
                displayScoreSA(scoreSA, wicketsSA);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.wideSA: {
                scoreSA += 1;
                displayScoreSA(scoreSA, wicketsSA);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.wicketSA: {
                wicketsSA += 1;
                displayScoreSA(scoreSA, wicketsSA);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.resetScore: {
                scoreIndia = 0;
                scoreSA = 0;
                wicketsIndia = 0;
                wicketsSA = 0;

                displayScoreIndia(scoreIndia, wicketsIndia);
                displayScoreSA(scoreSA, wicketsSA);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public void displayScoreIndia(int score, int wickets) {
        TextView scoreIndiaText   = findViewById(R.id.scoreIndiaText);
        TextView wicketsIndiaText = findViewById(R.id.wicketsIndiaText);

        scoreIndiaText.setText(String.valueOf(score));
        wicketsIndiaText.setText(" / " + String.valueOf(wickets));
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public void displayScoreSA(int score, int wickets) {
        TextView scoreSAText   = findViewById(R.id.scoreSAText);
        TextView wicketsSAText = findViewById(R.id.wicketsSAText);

        scoreSAText.setText(String.valueOf(score));
        wicketsSAText.setText(" / " + String.valueOf(wickets));
    }

}
```

## XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/cricketground" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#99000000">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <!-- INDIA COLUMN -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_india" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="INDIA"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/scoreIndiaText"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textSize="40sp"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/wicketsIndiaText"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" / 0"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/sixerIndia"
                            style="@style/CircleButton"
                            android:text="Sixer"/>
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/fourIndia"
                            style="@style/CircleButton"
                            android:text="Four"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/singleIndia"
                            style="@style/CircleButton"
                            android:text="Single"/>
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/twoIndia"
                            style="@style/CircleButton"
                            android:text="Two"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/noIndia"
                            style="@style/CircleButton"
                            android:text="No"/>
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/wideIndia"
                            style="@style/CircleButton"
                            android:text="Wide"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/wicketIndia"
                        style="@style/RoundedButtons"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="wicket" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- PARTITION -->
                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#33FFFFFF" />

                <!--SOUTH AFRICA COLUMN -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_south_africa" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="SOUTH AFRICA"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/scoreSAText"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textSize="40sp"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/wicketsSAText"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" / 0"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/sixerSA"
                            style="@style/CircleButton"
                            android:text="Sixer"/>
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/fourSA"
                            style="@style/CircleButton"
                            android:text="Four"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/singleSA"
                            style="@style/CircleButton"
                            android:text="Single"/>
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/twoSA"
                            style="@style/CircleButton"
                            android:text="Two"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/noSA"
                            style="@style/CircleButton"
                            android:text="No"/>
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/wideSA"
                            style="@style/CircleButton"
                            android:text="Wide"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/wicketSA"
                        style="@style/RoundedButtons"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="wicket" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/resetScore"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="reset"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing `int`. So just use

```
if (wicketsIndia == 10) {
    btnWicketIndia.setEnabled(false);
}
```

EDIT:

```
int wicketsSA    = 0;
Button btnWicketIndia; // DECLARE IT HERE

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    btnWicketIndia = findViewById(R.id.wicketIndia); // ASSIGN HERE
    ...
 }
```

Comment: As well as wicketsIndia is an int, so you would simply need to match the 10 not including the “\”, as the integer wicketsIndia will never contain a \

Comment: @nupadhyaya thanks but if you check `btnWicketIndia` it is giving error too. As that I have defined in `onCreate` method. So how can I get the button in `onClick` method and disable it?

Comment: declare your Buttons as member variables. And assign them inside the onCreate. check edit

Comment: Let me try by setting global

Comment: @nupadhyaya yeah it works that way. But it is disabeling on `11` value. Also is ther any other way without defining button globally?

Comment: It is not a global variable. Looks like you have c/c++ background. Java has either local variables (example:declaring inside onCreate) or class variable (which you think is global). Class variables are a standard way of creating variables in java. It is not the same as global variable of c/c++

Comment: @CodeLover It is disabling on 11 because you are disabling the button AFTER it has been clicked. This will prevent the listener from being triggered on further clicks, but it will not stop the rest of the code block from running. You can prevent the rest of the code from running by adding `return;` after disabling the button, but what you probably want is to disable the button as soon as the value reaches 10. To do that, move the code that checks the value and disables the button to `displayScoreIndia`, just after setting the text on `wicketsIndiaText`

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a look at the pattern you have chosen.

Use a ViewModel to hold the scores and wickets of the "home team" and the "away team".

Make some observers of the data in your activity/widget and respond to the changes.

You will need to add Google's/Android dependency to your App Gradle file:

```
 // ViewModel and LiveData
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
```

Here is an example showing a ViewModel and an Activity using an observer like pattern:

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.Observer;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;

//Extend FRAGMENT ACTIVITY
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Get handle on the ViewModel:
        final ViewModelMain viewModelMain = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModelMain.class);

        //Observe the data in the viewmodel class:
        viewModelMain.homeWickets.observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer integer) {
                //MAKE CHANGES WHEN THE VALUE FOR THE HOME WICKETS CHANGE LIKE SET ON CLICK METHODS TO NULL?
            }
        });

        viewModelMain.homeScore.observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer integer) {
                //MAKE CHANGES WHEN THE VALUE FOR THE HOME SCORE CHANGE LIKE SET ON CLICK METHODS TO NULL?
            }
        });

        //HOW TO SET A VIEW MODEL VALUE LIKE AFTER CLICKING A BUTTON:
        View v = new View(getApplicationContext());
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewModelMain.setHomeScore(viewModelMain.getHomeScore().getValue() + 1);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.arch.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel;
import android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

public class ViewModelMain extends AndroidViewModel {
    public ViewModelMain(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        // Set all values to 0 when constructed?

        this.awayScore.postValue(0);
        this.homeScore.postValue(0);
        this.homeWickets.postValue(0);
        this.awayWickets.postValue(0);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<Integer> awayScore = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<Integer> homeScore = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<Integer> homeWickets = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<Integer> awayWickets = new MutableLiveData<>();

    //SETTERS -> POST THE DATA TO THE MUTABLE FIELDS

    public void setAwayScore(Integer awayScore) {
        this.awayScore.postValue(awayScore);
    }

    public void setAwayWickets(Integer awayWickets) {
        this.awayWickets.postValue(awayWickets);
    }

    public void setHomeScore(Integer homeScore) {
        this.homeScore.postValue(homeScore);
    }

    public void setHomeWickets(Integer homeWickets) {
        this.homeWickets.postValue(homeWickets);
    }

    //STANDARD JAVA GETTERS

    public MutableLiveData<Integer> getAwayScore() {
        return awayScore;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<Integer> getAwayWickets() {
        return awayWickets;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<Integer> getHomeScore() {
        return homeScore;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<Integer> getHomeWickets() {
        return homeWickets;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and appreciate. Your answer looks great but as I mentioned I am still new to android so I need to learn your code step by step.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the "View Model" / "Observer pattern".
You have a variable that you want to watch for a change (when wickets == 10) and have your activity change to represent that.

Comment: Okay, sure will look. It will definitely help to gain my skill. Appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

`\` is a special character. So if you get a text that contains `\`, you must add `\` before.

```
if (wicketsIndiaText.getText().toString().equals(" \\ 10 ")) {
       btnWicketIndia.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. but I have another issue in it. If you check `btnWicketIndia` it is giving error too. As that I have defined in `onCreate` method. So how can I get the button in `onClick` method and disable it?

Comment: You can define them as global ?